# Can I globally apply [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to use this option:

```
namespace Japanese.Views
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class NewItemPage : ContentPage
```

Here I have placed it on top of the class code but is there a way that I can globally apply this option rather than place it on top of every class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, place it above your namespace declaration in the `App.xaml.cs` file. It should fall through to everything in that assembly.

Also see the Docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xamlc

Comment: I thought that but then I am looking at the sample app that gets created from File > New Solution in Xamarin and they have placed that same code above each of the partial classes in the files.  Any ideas why they would have done that?

Comment: On Windows? Because I do not see this happening when doing a File > New Solution on the Mac. So probably just a bug in the template.